# Windows 10 taskbar width is very wide when positioned on the sides

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, desktop-customization, appearance

Are there ways to reduce the Windows 10 taskbar width when it's positioned on the sides ?

It can be resized but the minimum width is very wide. It seems to have a minimum width to fit the date.

[image]

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you might find setting the taskbar to automatically hide in desktop mode convenient.

Comment: Autohide isn't what I need, I need a thinner taskbar.